# Magnific Popup Shows Iframe Loading, But Then Redirects To URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, magnific-popup

**Magnific Popup**

*I'm having buggy results with iframes using external URLS in Magnific Popup.*

**Issue**

When I open an iframe link with an external URL, it flashes the popup, sometimes even showing it loaded & then redirects me to the actual URL. I've tried multiple variations that didn't work, but here's what I currently have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open_iframe').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',
                iframe: {
                patterns: {
                    yourcustomsource: {
                        index: '',
                        src: '%id%'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Exceptions That Are Working**

- Loading the site it's installed on in a Magnific iframe
- Loading Youtube videos in a Magnific iframe
- If a gallery is created & it's initiated with a Youtube link or the site URL, it allows me to navigate through other external links fine.

*Overall, how do I stop this redirecting behavior so external URLs load correctly in the iframe?*

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the click event as follows to stop the redirection:

```
 $('.open_iframe').click(function(){
     return false;
 });
```

This worked for me.